# React native header placement of items

Tags: react-native

I made a header and I want to implement a play button and placed it on the right side in the same line as my header.

This is my header

```
class SectionHeader extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.header}>  
            <Text style={styles.headertext}>
            {this.props.section.title}       
            </Text>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
            <Text style ={styles.Play}>Play
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}
```

This is my style list

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({  
header:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(77,120, 140)',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
headertext:{
    fontSize: 25,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    margin: 20,
},
button:{
        alignItems: 'flex-end',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
play:{
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 20,
    color: 'white',       
    width: 45,
    height: 35,
    backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
    margin: 20,
}, 
});
```

This is the output. As you can see the Cluster 1 and play button shown. I want to place the cluster1 in the middle while the play button on the right side at the end instead of in the middle

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the way flex box works to achieve what you want you'll need to add an additional empty Text element to your header, and then on the header style set `justifyContent: 'space-between'`. If you do that you'll be able to remove the `alignItems` and `justifyContent` attributes from the button.

To place the Button on the end you'll have to use `alignSelf: 'flex-end'` instead of `alignContent` because the element style will be referring to itself and not its children alignment.

There is an excellent online course for free on flexbox called [Flexbox Zombies](https://mastery.games/p/flexbox-zombies). Believe me when I tell you its going to be fun learning all the flex attributes, and you won't ever forget them again.

Answer (score 0):

The way I usually do it is to set the header's style to use justifyContent as 'space-between' and then place an empty View as the first item (before the title).